# How to unit test a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, xunit

I have this piece of code on which I want to create a unit test and I am pretty new to that. So I just need some guidance on how should I start?

```
 public async Task<Response<TResult>> CallAuthenticatedApi<TRequest, TResult>(
        HttpMethod method,
        string uri,
        string[] scope,
        HttpSessionStateBase session,
        TRequest content = default(TRequest))
    {
        _logger.Information($"Making a call: {method} to {uri}");

        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var authToken = await GetAuthenticationToken(scope, session);

        var response = await RetryHelper.RetryOnExceptionAsync<HttpRequestException>(async () =>
        {
            var request = CreateRequestMessage(method, uri, stringContent, authToken);
            var response1 = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
            return response1;
        });

        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {

            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                _logger.Warning("User is unauthenticated");
                return new Response<TResult>(default(TResult),
                    response.StatusCode);



            default:
                var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _logger.Error("General failure when calling API! " +
                              $"Content: {errorContent}");
                return new Response<TResult>(default(TResult),
                    response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

I can test for response code but then I am confused what kind of info should I enter for the session even if I decide to create a mock?Please guide me on what should I pass in session variable

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the `session` variable are the least of your worries. If I was "pretty new" to unit testing and mocking, this would *not* be the code I would choose to learn on. The close-coupling of static method calls and the *cyclomatic complexity* (including the calls to other methods which are not given in the question) are going to make this very tricky.

For example, to test this, you're going to need to supply a URI of something which will genuinely have to respond to an http request. This is [integration testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing), which is valuable, but it's different than unit testing with mocking (which are tagged on the question).

Consider refactoring your code to separate your concerns into smaller responsibilities. Test that each of those parts does their job and `Verify` (using mock objects) that the parts are plugged together correctly.